# How do you attack someone with a bounty even though they come up as clean?

Tags: elite-dangerous

After picking up the bounty scanner I'm able to scan people and get a pretty big boost in bounty rewards, but I noticed some issues come up. Namely when they are clean in the system and I scan them. If a bounty shows up they are still listed as clean, which means I can't attack them without becoming wanted.

How can I claim that delicious bounty without getting wanted myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can control this, to a degree - if you are in a system that is policed (non-Anarchy) you will get a fine if you attack someone who shows up as clean.  The solution is to follow them when they hyperspace until they are in a system where they are wanted, or in an Anarchy system.  Not a great solution, but it is possible.

Of course, if you find them in an Anarchy system, you won't get a fine for attacking them whether they are wanted there or not.

Personally I don't bother chasing them, but to be honest, I tend not to find ships that are clean in the current system but wanted elsewhere - maybe because I don't do the interdicting myself - I let them interdict me then fight back.

Comment: if in a policed system and the police scan the ship in question will the tag change to wanted?

Comment: @Rapitor - No. They're wanted for crimes in other systems, but the local police/authorities only care about crimes in their system (or in systems/areas controlled by the same faction or major faction).